# Deploying Spring boot on Payara Glassfish

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, glassfish-4, payara

I am trying to deploy my Spring Boot app on Payara Galssfish server. But I get this error during the deployment.

> Error creating bean with name 'systemConfigDao': Initialization of
>   bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader
>   constraint violation: loader (instance of
>   org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoaderJava5)
>   previously initiated loading for a different type with name
>   "javax/cache/configuration/Configuration”

Comment: Have you turned off classloader delegation? We recommend it, especially for deploying Spring based applications! https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/content/documentation/extended-documentation/classloading.html

Comment: @Mike yes, I have. But I get the same error again

Comment: Payara ships with JCache Apis. Try adding JCache as a provided dependency.